# Create style for a new section

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, color

anyone can help me to do something like this?
for an informative section in my document
[image]

Comment: A question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Try to make your question clear & simple through a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Dear closing voters: from the three reasons appearing in Werner's comment "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear", could I ask which one are those voting to close choosing? This is neither "off topic", "too broad", nor "unclear", in my opinion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the versatile [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package; adjust the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{249,179,72}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,112,131}

\newtcolorbox{historical}{
sidebyside,
sidebyside align=top,
lefthand width=3cm,
sidebyside gap=14pt,
freelance,
interior code={},
frame code={},
overlay={
  \shade[top color=color2,bottom color=color2!10]
  ([xshift=6pt,yshift=8pt]frame.north west) 
    rectangle
  ([xshift=11pt,yshift=-6pt]frame.south west);
  \draw[color=color2,line width=1.5pt]
  ([yshift=4pt]title.north west) --
  ([yshift=4pt]title.north east);
  \draw[color=color2,line width=1.5pt]
  ([yshift=-2pt]frame.south west) --
  ([yshift=-2pt]frame.south east);
  },
colback=white,  
title=Historical,
center title,
title code={
  \fill[left color=color1,right color=color1!10]
  (title.north west)
    rectangle
  (title.south east);
  },
segmentation code={},
fonttitle=\large\sffamily\bfseries,
coltitle=black,
enlarge left by=-16pt,
enlarge right by=-16pt,
width=\textwidth+32pt,
left=15pt,
right=15pt,
before=\par\bigskip\noindent,  
after=\par\medskip
}

\newcommand\Name[1]{%
  \textcolor{color2}{\sffamily\bfseries #1}%
}
\newcommand\PersonInfo[1]{%
  {\par\smallskip\noindent\footnotesize\raggedright #1\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{historical}
\includegraphics[height=4.5cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\PersonInfo{Some text here describing the source of the image}
\tcblower
\Name{Alessandro Antonio Volta}
\lipsum[4]
\end{historical}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The historical information is simply provided through a `historical` environment and some auxiliary commands:

```
\begin{historical}
\includegraphics[height=4.5cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\PersonInfo{Some text here describing the source of the image}
\tcblower
\Name{Alessandro Antonio Volta}
text describing the person.
\end{historical}
```

And here's another option, using the also versatile [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) this time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{249,179,72}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,112,131}

\newmdenv[
hidealllines=true,
leftmargin=-16pt,
rightmargin=-16pt,
innerleftmargin=16pt,
innerrightmargin=16pt,
skipabove=35pt,
singleextra={
  \fill[overlay,left color=color1,right color=color1!10]
  ([yshift=4pt]O|-P)
    rectangle
  ([yshift=22pt]P);
  \node[overlay,font=\large\bfseries\sffamily] 
    at ([yshift=13pt] $ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) $ )
    {Historical};
  \shade[overlay,top color=color2,bottom color=color2!10]
  ([xshift=6pt,yshift=30pt]O|-P) 
    rectangle
  ([xshift=11pt,yshift=-8pt]O);
  \draw[overlay,color=color2,line width=1.5pt]
  ([yshift=25.5pt]O|-P) --
  ([yshift=25.5pt]P);
  \draw[overlay,color=color2,line width=1.5pt]
  ([yshift=-2pt]O) --
  ([yshift=-2pt]P|-O);
  },
]{historical}

\newcommand\Name[1]{%
  \textcolor{color2}{\sffamily\bfseries #1}%
}
\newcommand\PersonInfo[1]{%
  {\par\smallskip\noindent\footnotesize\raggedright #1\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{historical}
\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
\raisebox{-\dimexpr\totalheight-5pt\relax}{\includegraphics[height=4.5cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\PersonInfo{Some text here describing the source of the image}
\end{minipage}\hspace{15pt}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-3cm-15pt\relax}
\Name{Alessandro Antonio Volta}
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}
\end{historical}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now that's how one should be! Never say No!. Good work Gonzalo! :)

Comment: @user51976 You're welcome.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks! And, yes, never say No :)